# Eclipse and Maven: Run goal after a file is changed

Tags: eclipse, maven, compilation, phase

I have a maven goal configured in the pom that is executed on compile phase.
But also I need that goal to run after a specific file is changed to keep everything always up to date.

i.e I want to save the file "objects.xml" and run the goal "transform" to apply XSL every time a change is done.

Is there a way for doing that from inside Eclipse?

I've been reading about custom builders for the project, but that does not cover my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add builders and custom ant scripts to your eclipse workspace.

Project->Preferences->Builders

These builders can be automatically be added to you project with

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

By adding the folling config to your pom

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>your.custom.Builder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
```

for more info how to do this see the maven-eclipse-plugin website

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: Can you give an example for the specific case in the question?